# find past value in growth rate equation

Tags: finance, percentages

I know the following things for a problem.

Percent growth over a 3 year period was 11,200%

The present value is $24,000,000
And the past value is x

The growth rate equation is `% growth = (Present - Past) / Past` 
Which gives me this:

```
11,200% = (24,000,000 - x) / x
```

How would I solve for x?

Comment: You need to isolate x

Comment: @Brandon so would that get me `x = 24000000/11201, which equals 2142?

Comment: @Brandon and does the fact that this is a 3 year growth rate make any difference? or the result still stands?

Comment: @Brandon got it. but do i need to account for the % at all by taking off two 0's in the percent? something seems off. When I do 2142*11200% i dont get 24mm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are given a percentage we will need to divide by 100%

$$\frac{11200}{100}=\frac{24000000-x}{x}$$

After cross multiplying you obtain

$$11200 x=2400000000-100 x$$

After adding 100x to both sides

$$11300 x = 2400000000$$

Then, solve for x

$$x=\frac{2400000000}{11300}$$

$$x = 212389$$

Comment: awesome thanks. last question. When I do 2142*11200% i dont get 24mm. what am i missing?

Comment: is there no x100 because the %?

Comment: i think x should be 212,389 because its a %. https://www.mathpapa.com/algebra-calculator.html?q=11200%5C%25%5C%20%3D%5C%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(24000000-x%5Cright)%7D%7Bx%7D

Comment: Oh ok. youre probably right. I haven't worked with percentages in a long time. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: all good. feel free to update your answer. thanks for helping me get there.

Comment: yeah I was a bit off. I'm glad you figured it out though. I even learned some things

Comment: @rs19 you can delete the comments since they wont serve any purpose to you or any other viewers